# Removing Active Directory 2003

Tags: active-directory

I have a domain controller which runs Windows Server 2003 r2 32 bit and I want to upgrade it to 2008 r2 64 bit. I installed 2008 r2 on another server and made it the additional of 2003 domain controller and it works fine and tranfered all Operation Master roles on it and made it Global Catolog but when trying to remove active directory from dc 2003 with dcpromo command it gives me an error that all global catalogs are dawn and there is no contact with another doamin controller in network and so it can not remove active directory from dc 2003

Comment: what's the output from dcdiag?

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the "Active Directory Sites and Services", expand the site where the new server is exists, right click on the new Windows 2008 server and in the NTDS settings define it as Global Catalog. Give it some time to replicate data from Windows 2003 before you issue dcpromo on it.

Comment: "Transferred all Operation Master roles on it and made it Global Catalogue" <- He's already made it a GC.

Answer (score 0):

On each server, use the `repadmin` command to ensure replication is occurring.  Specifically, use the `repadmin /syncall <DC>`  command first, where DC is the name of the domain controller, on each DC.  If that completes and still you can't use dcpromo to demote the server 2003 DC, use the `repadmin /showrepl` command on each DC to get a pointer to where to look next.

You can also try seizing each role on the new DC, if replication is working but dcpromo is still denied.  You may need to seize the roles to the 2003 DC and then transfer them to the new DC.